# Selenium and excel

Tags: java, excel, firefox, selenium

I need to write a code that uses excel file cells to fill up information on a website.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("A-TOTAL-AREA")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("A-TOTAL-AREA")).sendKeys("89");
```

For example, so that the Total area will be taken from the excel instead of "hard coding" it in.

Comment: you have several questions with quality answers, including this, but you have accepted none as answers. Please consider using the Accept answer button to reward those who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using POI jar to access excel sheet data. Refer:- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/